# Chat search is broken again

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, search

I can't perform a search on chat for something I said. It just takes forever, and after forever has passed, the 500 lolcat pops up.

Here's an example: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=chat+search+sucks&user=46642&room=10.

If I search without limiting it to my posts, like https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=chat+search+sucks&room=10, it works fine.

Comment: I see lolcats too on the first link, but weirdly http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=chat+search+sucks&user=46642&room= works fine withou the room, so it seems the combination of room + user is the problem

Comment: I can search for times I said "bananas", or "search" just fine, but when I search for  "chat search sucks" and a user, it fails.  Still testing.

Comment: Should be at least a little bit better now. A round of index tuning is in order.

Answer (score 3):

Chat search is backed by elastic search now so this should no longer be an issue.

Comment: I think it's broken again.  I'm getting 0 results for everything.