# Chat search is broken for a deleted room

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, search, deleted-room

This may be something to do with the recent downtime and relocation of SE servers to Colorado; I think that was around the time I started noticing problems.

**Chat search is broken, apparently displaying only results up to ~2015.**

I guarantee there should be more results for searches like [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=belgariad&room=198) and [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=rand&user=&room=198), but nothing is displaying after around autumn 2015. This is very annoying, because there are a lot of things said in chat that I'd like to find again (for example, right now I want to find the mini-reviews of the Belgariad series which I posted in chat in order to turn them into a published mini-review for a blog).

<sub>Not a duplicate of [Chat search is broken again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134964/278659) - that one's from 5 years ago and presumably a different underlying issue.</sub>

Comment: umm.... [it's working fine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=belgariad&user=&room=), you searched in a specific room. If you mean it's broken for a specific room you should really mention this in the bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not working fine, because it's not displaying newer results *from that room* (which is where I wrote my mini-reviews). I don't know whether there are other rooms whose results aren't displaying.

Comment: @Sha - yeah, and that's what's broken. I've had trouble searching for stuff that I *know* was posted in a specific room and not found it.

Comment: The room is frozen and deleted. I guess this cause it to not be indexed.

Comment: OK, confirmed it's a bug with deleted rooms, e.g. [here on MSE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Israel&room=488) as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The room *is* indexed, just not after mid-2015. And searchability of that particular room is important, because it's historically been one of the most active chatrooms on the network and there's loads of useful/important stuff in its archives.

Comment: @Philippe, are you considering fixing our current chat, or are you planning on building something new and better?

Comment: @Luuklag I am more curious what made him put this one, out of thousands of open bugs, in review. It's far from being major, more close to very minor. So, random selection? Maybe using some script? No idea.

Comment: @Shadow Neither random nor a script :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor how can you know?

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron  he's a Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Marking this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) since we are not going to be able to get to it in the near term due to the difficulty of fixing issues like this in chat (and it's accompanying Elastic service that is used for search indexing). It will stay in our books as an issue to fix if/when we are able to prioritize chat issues like this again.

Comment: Wouldn't [tag:status-deferred] be more appropriate then? "Indicates that the feature request or bug has merit to consider, but will not be implemented or fixed in the near term."

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I think the implication of [tag:status-deferred] is that is absolutely will get done. Declined means, they'll pick it up if and only iff it's still an issue later on.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage no. Deferred should mean it might be done. Planned should mean it will be done almost for sure. Declined should mean it will never be done. That's just my common sense, and sadly not shared by SE, hence the terrible mixup all those tags create. But it doesn't matter, when only 1-2 bugs are fixed every month, best case, and there are thousands of bugs.... you can do the math yourself.

Comment: "*we are not going to be able to get to it in the near term*", the info of the [status-deferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) tag even says something similar "*will not be implemented or fixed in the near term*". [status-deferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) seems to be best here. Anyways, someone needs to address the actual meaning of "*bug will not be fixed at present time*" in the description of [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined), its description probably needs a change.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron I'm basing what I said off of a private conversation with CMs/Devs. I agree the tags are confusing (as evidenced by your comments) but I can't change it myself.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage that does not matter. So they should put an order into this chaos and edit the tags. They don't, so I can't rely on "private conversation", sorry.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron I'm telling you how they use it. I'm not saying the tags shouldn't be edited. I'm trying to help you explain *the current situation* to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I guess so, it's just a little bit confusing... Well, now that we have a standalone post about it, maybe we can agree on a solution that works for everyone (either editing the wikis, adjusting the usage, or both)

Comment: I think the [tag:status-declined] tag here is correct. The extended description for the tag has the following text: *[This tag] can also come up if the bug report is determined to be valid (i.e. not [tag:status-bydesign]), but the team has decided not to fix the bug for technical or performance reasons, i.e. that fixing the bug would lead to further performance issues or introduce other bugs.* This answer fits perfectly into that. OTOH, the one for [tag:status-deferred] states that it's for if it's been evaluated as positive on potential but can't be implemented due to external reasons.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog - "*can't be implemented due to external reasons*",  I also see the word "*near-term*" in the description of [status-deferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) btw.