# Searching in deleted chatrooms doesn’t work

Tags: bug, chat, chat-search

I recently got to 10K Network-wide, and was looking at a certain deleted chatroom using my powers. There was a specific message I was looking for, so I went into the search box and typed it in...no results. I tried a few different things that definitely should have results, but I got none. **Searching in deleted chatrooms doesn’t work.**

Comment: Dupe? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298497/398063 (I guess one of the chatrooms mentioned there is the one you were looking in...)

Comment: Not a duplicate—that’s about searching for stuff after 2015. [Searching for “fortress has no results”](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fortress&room=198) (10K total rep. needed), even though that was definitely said in 2011.