# How are 'status-deferred' and 'status-declined' used by staff?

Tags: support, status-review, tags, stack-exchange-team, moderator-tags

This isn't covered by [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/175002), as that just explains the tags, but I want to know how they are used by the staff. From experience this differs from the tag description.

As an example, see this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376733/175002):

> Marking this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) since we are not going to be able to get to it in the near term due to the difficulty of fixing issues like this in chat (and it's accompanying Elastic service that is used for search indexing). *It will stay in our books as an issue to fix if/when we are able to prioritize chat issues like this again.*

(Emphasis mine)

Where the excerpt for [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) reads as:

> Indicates that the feature request will not be implemented, or that a bug will not be fixed at present time.

with its extended description reading:

> A feature request or bug report is considered declined if the report is reviewed and the site developers disagree that the feature should be implemented or the bug should be fixed.

However [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)'s excerpt reads as:

> Indicates that the feature request or bug has merit to consider, but will not be implemented or fixed in the near term.

with the extended description saying:

> A feature request or bug with this tag is something that has been evaluated as positive on potential, but is not present in the current work timeline. It is also not guaranteed to be implemented - when it resurfaces, the proposal may be re-evaluated and a new decision made depending on how the situation has changed since then.

By all rights, based on the wiki excerpts it looks like that [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) should have had [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). but my understanding, based on private conversations with staff, is that [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) is only used for things that are part of a long term plan, i.e. absolutely intended to be done, just not soon.

My guess is there is no plan long term or otherwise to get the linked chat issue completed, even though they recognise it would be worth doing. Had it been [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) it would imply  that feature was planned, regardless of how far off implementing that plan would be (years, decades, whatever).

Is this how the staff use the tag? Do the tag wikis need updating?

Comment: Welcome to the Land of Chaos, where status tags are lost. :)

Comment: @V2Blast perfect example of the chaos I'm talking about. Tag wiki excerpt of the [tag:status-review] tag that you applied: *Indicates that the circumstances behind a **bug report** are set to be internally reviewed*. Do note, this is not a bug report. It is a support question, or discussion. Everything is a mess.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron: Relevant MSE post: [What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251) I figured this Q&A, though a support question, could use an official response from staff, since only staff can really answer it (and because there has been confusion around how the tags are used). Though I think that the linked post makes [status-review] one of the clearer tags in terms of how we use it...

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron unfair. The incorrect wording was added by community member(s). The original wording from staff members was clear and unambiguous as `Indicates that the report contains merit to consider, but the decision on its approval or decline requires more investigation.` This is neither chaos or everything being a mess, it's wording that's not as precise/correct as you'd perhaps like. The intent is still fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron *we don't live in an ideal world*; that much should be pretty obvious based on the past few years of real world events, if nothing else. Chill.

Comment: I suggest also including quotes from the extended tag wikis from each tag, not just the excerpts.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog I just went to look, they're fairly long and not accurate either? Feel free to edit them in, but I will hold off for now

Comment: Edited in. I'd say that the current tag used is valid, due to the third paragraph of [tag:status-declined]'s extended description: *[This tag] can also come up if the bug report is determined to be valid (i.e. not [tag:status-bydesign]), but the team has decided not to fix the bug for technical or performance reasons, i.e. that fixing the bug would lead to further performance issues or introduce other bugs.*

Comment: @Sonic I honestly don't think you, me, or anyone else who does not work for SE can, or should, edit the red tags wiki. We can't possibly know how SE really use those tags, so everything is just a guess, naturally usually wrong. This only leads to confusion when the tags are used against what's written in the wiki, as happening these days.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron We can, however, look at past uses of the tags and document how they've been used. (The part quoted in this question was added by a staff member, by the way.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron we absolutely can know how SE uses those tags, we just need to asks a question on meta about how SE uses... Wait a moment... That's *this* question 

Comment: @AncientSwordRage e.x.a.c.t.l.y. ;)